# Azure DevOps nunit test execution very slow

Tags: azure, nunit, devops

We are migrating our DevOps to Azure. We are experiencing a significant increase in time required to run our unit tests using nunit. A host is configured with the remote agent and the job is executed on this machine. The tests are on a .Net framework solution written in C#.

Previously, we used Jenkins for the DevOps with an agent on the same computer. The test job was a lot faster. On Jenkins, the job was executed in about 2h30min. In Azure DevOps, it failed after 5h (it was the configured timeout), so not even completed.

Here is the yaml code in Azure :

```
  - task: VSTest@2
    timeoutInMinutes: 600
    inputs:
      testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
      testAssemblyVer2: '*.Test*.dll'
      searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)'
      codeCoverageEnabled: false
      platform: 'Any CPU'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
      rerunFailedTests: false
      pathtoCustomTestAdapters: 'Solution/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter.3.12.0/build/net35'
      minimumExpectedTests: 1000
      runInParallel: true
      failOnMinTestsNotRun: true
      resultsFolder: 'testResults'
    continueOnError: true
```

On Jenkins, the job was configured this way:

```
stage('Testing'){
    when{
        expression{ params.runTests == true}
    }
    steps{
        bat "MSBuild.exe Solution\\Vibrosight.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=\"Any CPU\" /t:Rebuild /maxcpucount:4"
        bat returnStatus:false, script: '''nunit3-console.exe Solution\\Vibrosight.sln --config=Debug --agents=1 --result=TestResult.xml;format=nunit2 --timeout=900000 --workers=1
        exit 0'''               
        nunit testResultsPattern: 'TestResult.xml'              
    }
}
```

Does anyone have some tips on how I could improve the nunit test execution on Azure DevOps ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: One noticeable change is that you've gone from running your test assemblies sequentially, to running them in parallel. If your test run isn't completing on Azure, is there anything that could be causing a deadlock between different test assemblies? It might be worth enabling the `diagnosticsEnabled` option, to see if a particular test is causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much Chris for your answer. I figured out that one test was blocked indeed. A popup dialog with an ok button waiting for the user to acknowledge was blocking the test. I don't know why it was not the case with Jenkins. Anyway I ignored the test and then everything passed in also 2h30min, as before. I keep you idea of diagnosticsEnabled, that will be very helpful for the next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, a test was blocking the execution. After ignoring this test, the run was ok and with almost the same time as before. Thanks again Chris your tips.